# Python how to convert object to the timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have two columns with the time stamp(hours and minutes precisions) and is been read as object in pandas. I need to calculate the difference is there a better way to do it??

```
Col1        Col2
21:40.9     21:41
21:41       21:41
21:41.123   21:41
21:41.2.    21:41
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1','Col2','Diff'])
df['Col1'] = [dt.strptime('21:40.9', '%M:%S.%f'), dt.strptime('21:41', '%M:%S'), dt.strptime('21:41.123', '%M:%S.%f'), dt.strptime('21:41.2', '%M:%S.%f')]
df['Col2'] = [dt.strptime('21:41', '%M:%S'), dt.strptime('21:41', '%M:%S'), dt.strptime('21:41', '%M:%S'), dt.strptime('21:41', '%M:%S')]
df['Diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Col2 - x.Col1 if x.Col2 > x.Col1 else x.Col1 - x.Col2, axis=1)
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%M:%S.%f'))
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%M:%S.%f'))

print(df)
```

with output:

```
           Col1          Col2            Diff
0  21:40.900000  21:41.000000 00:00:00.100000
1  21:41.000000  21:41.000000        00:00:00
2  21:41.123000  21:41.000000 00:00:00.123000
3  21:41.200000  21:41.000000 00:00:00.200000
```

unfortunately, the format of your data is not consistent (`21:41` vs `21:40.9`) thus it is bit longer to convert them to the same format.